# How to select and manipulate the dynamically created html element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to js, and I am building a color scheme generator as a solo project.
I am now stuck on select the html element that created from dynamically.
I tried to select both label and input element below, using document.getElementByClassName but it gives me 'undefined'

I wanna select both label and input elements and add an click eventListner so that they can copy the result color code from that elements.

```
 <label for='${resultColor}' class='copy-label'>Click to copy!</label>
 <input class='result-code' id='${resultColor}' type="text" value='${resultColor}'/>`
```

```js
const colorPickerModes = [ 'monochrome', 'monochrome-dark', 'monochrome-light', 'analogic',  'complement', 'analogic-complement',  'triad quad']
const colorPickerForm = document.getElementById("colorPick-form");
const colorPickerInput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
const colorPickerModeDropDown = document.getElementById("colorPick-mode");

const resultColorDiv = document.getElementById("result-color-div");
const resultColorCodeDiv = document.getElementById("result-code-div");

let colorPicked = "";
let modePicked = "";
let resultColorDivHtml =''
let resultCodeDivHtml=''
let colorSchemeSetStrings = [];
let resultColorSchemeSet = [];

    fetchToRender()
    renderDropDownList();

//listen when user change the color input and save that data in global variable
colorPickerInput.addEventListener(
  "change",
  (event) => {
    //to remove # from the color hex code data we got from the user
    colorPicked = event.target.value.slice(1, 7);
  },
  false
);

//listen when user change the scheme mode dropdownlist value and save that data in global variable
colorPickerModeDropDown.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{

    modePicked = 
    colorPickerModeDropDown.options[colorPickerModeDropDown.selectedIndex].text;
})

//whe user click submit btn get data from user's input
colorPickerForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {

  event.preventDefault();
  // To get options in dropdown list
  modePicked =
    colorPickerModeDropDown.options[colorPickerModeDropDown.selectedIndex].text;
    fetchToRender()

});


//when first load, and when user request a new set of color scheme
function fetchToRender(){

    if (!colorPicked) {
        //initialize the color and mode value if user is not selected anything
        colorPicked = colorPickerInput.value.slice(1, 7);
        modePicked = colorPickerModes[0]
      }

    fetch(
        `https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex=${colorPicked}&mode=${modePicked}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          let colorSchemeSetArray = data.colors;
         

          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            colorSchemeSetStrings.push(colorSchemeSetArray[i]);
          }
    
          // to store each object's hex value
          for (let i = 0; i < colorSchemeSetStrings.length; i++) {
            resultColorSchemeSet.push(colorSchemeSetStrings[i].hex.value);
          }
          renderColor();
          colorSchemeSetStrings = []
          resultColorSchemeSet = [];
    
        });
}

function renderColor(){

    //to store result of color scheme set object

      resultColorDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet.map((resultColorItem) => {
        return `<div class="result-color" 
        style="background-color: ${resultColorItem};"></div>`;
      }).join('')

      resultCodeDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet
        .map((resultColor) => {
          return `
                 <label for='${resultColor}' class='copy-label'>
                 Click to copy!</label>
                 <input class='result-code' id='${resultColor}' 
                 type="text" value='${resultColor}'/>`;
        })
        .join("");

        
      resultColorDiv.innerHTML = resultColorDivHtml;
      resultColorCodeDiv.innerHTML = resultCodeDivHtml;

}

function renderDropDownList() {
  const colorPickerModeOptionsHtml = colorPickerModes
    .map((colorPickerMode) => {
      return `<option class='colorSchemeOptions' value="#">${colorPickerMode}</option>`;
    })
    .join("");

  colorPickerModeDropDown.innerHTML = colorPickerModeOptionsHtml;
 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

/*------Layout------*/

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#form-div {
  width: 100%;
  height:10vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#colorPick-form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height:6vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#colorPick-form > * {
  margin: 1rem;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px lightgray solid;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  
}

#colorPick-form > #colorPicker {
  width: 14%;
  height: inherit;
  
}

#colorPick-form > #colorPick-mode {
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

#colorPick-form > #btn-getNewScheme {
  width: 26%;
}

#main {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
  margin: .8em  auto 0;
  height: 75vh;
  border:lightgray 1px solid;
}


#result-color-div {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    display:flex;

}
#result-color-div > *{

    width:calc(100%/5);
}

#result-code-div {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    display:flex;
}

.copy-label{
    width:10%;
    display:flex;
    padding:0.5em;
    font-size:0.8rem;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;

}

#result-code-div .result-code{

    width:calc(90%/5);
    text-align: center;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.result-code:hover, .result-code:focus, .copy-label:hover, .copy-label:focus{
    font-weight:700;

}


/*------Button------*/

#btn-getNewScheme {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #614385 0%,
    #516395 51%,
    #614385 100%
  );
}


#btn-getNewScheme {
  padding:0.8rem 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn-getNewScheme:hover,
#btn-getNewScheme:focus {
  background-position: right center; /* change the direction of the change here */
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Color Scheme Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div>
      <header><h1 class="site-title"> Color Scheme Generator </h1></header>
    </div>
      <div id="form-div">
        <form id="colorPick-form" method="get" >
          <input id="colorPicker" type="color" />
          <select name="colorPick-mode" id="colorPick-mode">
 
          </select>
          <button type='submit' id="btn-getNewScheme">Get Color Scheme</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="main">
        <div id="result-color-div">

        </div>
        <div id="result-code-div">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add some more code, what did you already try? And it will be great if you share you minimal runnable code here in SO Code Snippet

Comment: just modified! with all the code I wrote, thanks for looking into my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is rendering timing. So you need to add event listener below the code where set innerHTML.

```js
function renderColor() {
  // to store result of color scheme set object
  resultColorDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet
    .map((resultColorItem) => {
      return `<div class="result-color" style="background-color: ${resultColorItem};"></div>`;
    })
    .join("");

  resultCodeDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet
    .map((resultColor) => {
      return `
<label for='${resultColor}' class='copy-label'>Click to copy!</label>
<input class='result-code' id='${resultColor}' type="text" value='${resultColor}'/>
`;
    })
    .join("");

  resultColorDiv.innerHTML = resultColorDivHtml;
  resultColorCodeDiv.innerHTML = resultCodeDivHtml;

  // here! add event listener
  const labels = document.getElementsByClassName("result-code");
  Object.entries(labels).forEach(([key, label]) => {
    label.addEventListener("click", (event) =>
      alert(`copy color: ${event.target.value}`)
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: You made my code working perfectly. I was stuck on this part for like hours. Thank you so so so much for your help!

Comment: That's nice. Then please choose my answer. Thank you.

Comment: How can I choose your answer tho? Im just super new here.

Comment: There is the check button next my answer. reference link - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const resultColorCodeDiv=document.getElementById("resultColorCodeDiv")
const resultColorDiv=document.getElementById("resultColorDiv")
resultColorSchemeSet=[
              {color:"red", code: "#ff0000"},
              {color:"green", code: "#00ff00"},
              {color:"blue", code: "#0000ff"}]

function renderColor(){

    //to store result of color scheme set object

      resultColorDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet.map((resultColorItem) => {
        return `<div class="result-color" style="background-color: ${resultColorItem.color};"></div>`
      }).join('')

      resultCodeDivHtml = resultColorSchemeSet
        .map((resultColor) => {
          return  `
                    <label for='${resultColor.code}' class='copy-label'>Click to copy!</label>
                    <input class='result-code' id='${resultColor.code}' type="text" value='${resultColor.code}'/>`
        })
        .join("")

        
      resultColorDiv.innerHTML = resultColorDivHtml
      resultColorCodeDiv.innerHTML = resultCodeDivHtml
      
      addListener(document.querySelectorAll(".result-color"))
      addListener(document.querySelectorAll(".result-code"))

}

renderColor()

function addListener(elements){

    for(const element of elements){
            element.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
            // add copy logic here
            console.log("hello")
            })
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="resultColorDiv"></div>
<div id="resultColorCodeDiv"></div>
</body>
```